# Can I add a password hint to protected pdf file?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using tfpdf for creating a file and at certain stage I am using the Tcpdi library to load the file and protect it with password.

is there any way to set a password hint?

like: the password is your birth date...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't set a password hint with the TCPDI library.

Compare with *[TCPDF SetProtection method is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63534064/367456)* <sup>Q&A contribution</sup> for more information.

Comment: the question is "can I", so the answer should be "no". And when answering to a negative question, a clearer reply would be "indeed you can't".

Comment: @CasparV. Thanks for the edit, the abbrevation as given was wrong not by character case but by the characters alone. Just in case you had the impression I'm being pedantic.

Comment: TCPDI is an extension on TCPDF library. It would be better to correct the OP instead (so they can argue if the correction is applicable or not), instead of copying their writing and assuming they mean something else. I've edited your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

PDF passwords are optional, that is the only one essentially required to edit is the one to decrypt to view, since a viewed PDF is decrypted,  decompressed, decoded, and derestricted as required for disability/display/edit/select/highlight/print etc.. That last one has flags For Adobe Apps DRM usage but needs not be followed.

So if for any reason you need to add a hint by far the easiest is use a zip file with the text `Hint password for attached PDF open to view and edit is Blah Blah` or much simpler do what I did here and use the filename.

[image]